# How to multiply every two elements of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list(string): []

I need to multiply every two elements and than sum up the results

So for the list:[0,1,2,3,4]

I need to get the result: 105.

(0+1)×(1+2)×(2+3)×(3+4)=105

How do I do that?

I tried to write this code:

```py
Lst3= [0,1,2,3,4]

multiply=0

sum=0

count=1

for i in lst3:

  multiply= i*lst3[i+1]

  sum= sum+multiply 

  count=count+1

print (sum)
```

Comment: The expression `(0+1)×(1+2)×(2+3)×(3+4)` most certainly does not reflect the requirement "I need to multiply every two elements and than sum up the results"!

Comment: The expression `0*1+0*2+0*3+0*4+1*2+1*3+1*4+2*3+2*4+3*4` does.

Comment: (1) In the formula you add each two numbers and make the product of the results. (2) Format your code correctly as code.

Comment: so how do i change the title? i dont know how to phrase the question right lol

Comment: You need to iterate over the range of the list. `for i in range(len(lst3))-1: multiply = multiply * (lst3[i] + lst3[i+1]`

Comment: (1) Python is case-sensitive. (2) You try to use "i" as index (in brackets) but it is an item of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#zip) to achieve it. `zip` is a built-in class, which collects items from the same index of multiple iterators and returns an iterator. In your case, you want to add two adjacent items in a list, so you need to pass two lists to `zip` with one shifting an item out.

```py
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

result = 1
for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    result *= a + b
print(result)
# 105
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain _what_ this does and how it works; `zip` is quite a bit of magic to beginners. Thank you for actually answering OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

for (0+1)*(1+2)*(2+3)*(3+4)

```
    lst1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    # mul is the multiplication variable that stores the result
    # It is given 1 as its value as we are multiplying with it
    mul = 1
    # the for loop will literate from the first to the second last element in the list
    for i in range(0, len(lst1) - 1):
            # a local variable that stores the sum of the 2 values
            sumval = lst1[i] + lst1[i+1]
            mul = mul * sumval
    # print the result
    print(mul)
```

the result will be:
105

or (0x1)+(1x2)+(2x3)+(3x4)

```
    lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
            mul = lst[i] * lst[i+1]
            sum = sum + mul
    print(sum)
```

the logic is the same as the fist one

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
num = [0,1,2,3,4]

sum = 1
for i in range(len(num)-1):
    a = num[i] + num[i+1]
    sum = sum * a
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : Group elemnts until length is 2 & then sum them. Multiply at last

```
import math
l=[0,1,2,3,4]

cu=   [l[i] + l[(i+1)%len(l)] for i in range (len(l)-1)]          
print(math.prod(cu))
```

#otput

```
105
```

### SOlution 2

Access the index. index +1 will be next elemnt sum them accordingly. Multiply at lst uisng math

```
import math
l=[0,1,2,3,4]

cu=  [l[i] + l[i+1] for i in range (len(l)-1)]
print(cu)


print(math.prod(cu))
```

output #

```
105
```